# Link to chatter profile page from Community custom visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, community, chatter

I have custom visualforce page which displayed which available in Communities. It has profile menu where it have two options:

- Profile - navigate to Chatter profile profile
- Logout - logout action

I have figured the logout link, however, I want to know how I can link in the Chatter profile page on the profile menu. What things do I need to enable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are concerned with link only then you can create a chatter link as

```
https://{!salesforce_instance_base_url}/{!site_prefix}/_ui/core/userprofile/UserProfilePage?u={!UserID_here}&tab=sfdc.ProfilePlatformFeed
```

You will need to find out the URL of community for base url. ID of the user can be get by Global Visualforce functions